# Creating an android appwidget ListView for SDK 8?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-appwidget

I've developed a small android application which scrapes data from webpage. I've written a custom Adapter (using BaseAdapter) to display the data in a ListView (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2).

Now I thought it would be nice to have an app widget wich will display the scraped data, but it seems that you can't use ListView below SDK 11 in AppWidgets. I want to support at least SDK version 8.

Is there anything like a ListView which I could use to display the data as a home screen widget in SDK version 8 comfortably?